# Hiding X and Y axes from Plotly GeoPanda

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas, figure

This is just asking how to remove the x and y numbers in the GeoPanda graph WITHOUT removing the labels.

```
ax.axis(False)
```

I have tried the above code and then try to reapply the y and x labels but I can't. There is also no way to add custom labels with:

```
text(locx, locy, text)
```

If anyone knows how to turn off the values on the x and y lines without loosing the labels. Please tell me.